# What happened to Sideswipe in "Transformers: Dark of the Moon"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-dark-of-the-moon

After *Dark of the Moon*, we know that the Autobots where hunted down and killed by the humans following the battle of Chicago. But we never really saw Sideswipe die by the hands of humans. What happened to him?

Comment: Sideswipe don't die, he survive with Bumblebee, but we don't know nothing of him in "age of extinction". Some persons suggest thats he die in the last movie ( [read this](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Sideswipe_(Movie)#Age_of_Extinction_Topps_Europe_collector_cards) ) but we can't know this now just need to wait to the next movie for saw if he appers or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [*Transformers* wiki](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Sideswipe_(Movie)#Age_of_Extinction_Topps_Europe_collector_cards), he was killed by Cemetery Wind offscreen sometime after the battle of Chicago.

However that was not sourced and all I could find was Michael Bay decided not to cast roles for Sideswipe in *Transformers: Age of Extinction* and again in *Transformers: The Last Knight*.